# background-size doesn't work with 100%

Tags: html, css

I try to make background with image, this [image](http://patwoj.hekko24.pl/zdrowie/images/losos.jpg)
I have this code (page on bootstrap).

```css
.cover-losos{
  background: url('http://patwoj.hekko24.pl/zdrowie/images/losos.jpg') no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 cover-losos">
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Why isn't the photo showing? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: define height for your div ? It has width from bootstrap's col-md-12, but no height that I can see ..

Comment: use min-height:400px and you will see you background image. http://jsfiddle.net/6w98hp1n/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your issue is not the background. Your div where you set the background has neither a `width` nor a `height` set meaning that the size of the background image is 100% of 0px.

try adding a width and height to your `cover-losos` div.

```css
.cover-losos {
  background: url('https://placeimg.com/640/480/any') no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: 100%;
  -moz-background-size: 100%;
  -o-background-size: 100%;
  background-size: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12 cover-losos">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: But I want to do it responsive. It should take 100% width and height auto.

Comment: @patwoj98 are you planning on having any other content in your div or just the background image? You can't use height:auto on a div without content. This will just result in giving the div a height of 0px. You could add a height defined in percent if you wish.

Comment: I want make a background-image and on it I'll put 2 divs with texts

Comment: @patwoj98 if you plan on having your divs within the `.cover-losos` div you can set the height to auto. Like so: [http://jsfiddle.net/ah1yf2fu/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/ah1yf2fu/1/)